# How to make font size be as large as possible to fit screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a terminal-like app with JS. I want to be able to change the color of individual characters, so I decided to use a lot of spans to display them. Each span contains only one character. [This is what I ended up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGJl1.png). It works fine, but I want the "span screen" (green outline) to fit the screen as much as it can. It should scale but keep ascpect ratio. [I posted the code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/nirexd/pen/qBQKPgy).

I tried changing the size of the div that contains spans, but it didn't help. Then I tried changing the font size of spans, but it didn't help either. Maybe there's a better way to accomplish it all.

UPDATE: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI6n1.png) is how it is now, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZd71.png) is how it should be.

Here's the code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", draw);

function draw() {
  game = document.getElementById("game");
  for (y = 0; y <= 25; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
      cell = document.createElement("span");
      cell.innerText = "1";
      game.appendChild(cell);
    }
    game.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px red inset;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#game {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px green inset;
}

span {
  font-family: Cascadia Code;
}
```

```html
<div id='game'></div>
```

Comment: All the elements in the body element are centred both vertically and horizontally because of `display: flex;  justify-content: center; align-items: center;`

Comment: Could you describe what ‘as much as it can’ means in this context? Under what circumstances would it not fit the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting HTML elements to scale exactly can be tricky.

But SVG's are designed to be scaled, so if yo build your terminal inside an SVG things become much easier.

Below is a working snippet, I've adjusted the Row & Cols to just fit nicer inside a SO Snippet.  You can also make the SVG scale X & Y with the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute, click the SVG to see the difference.

```js
const tw = 10;
const th = 12;

const numCols = 40;
const numRows = 32;


function getNode(n, v) {
  n = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", n);
  for (var p in v)
    n.setAttributeNS(null, p, v[p]);
  return n
}

function draw() {
  const svg = getNode('svg', {
    viewBox: `0 0 ${tw*numCols} ${th*numRows}`});
  svg.style.display = 'block';
  for (y = 0; y < numRows; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < numCols; x++) {
      cell = getNode('text', {
        "alignment-baseline":"hanging",
        x: x * tw,
        y: y * th,
        class: 'cell',
       });
      cell.innerHTML = (x+y)%10;
      svg.appendChild(cell);
    }
  }
  game.appendChild(svg);
  
  svg.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const p = svg.getAttribute('preserveAspectRatio');
    svg.setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 
       p === 'none' ? '' : 'none');
  });
}

draw();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.cell {
  font-family: courier;
}

#game {
  height: 100%;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id='game'>
</div>
```

Comment: in general it works very well, but I found a bug: it cuts off one row and one col https://imgur.com/XOyTyjw https://imgur.com/A3W4U9p

Comment: @Nire  Yeah, just some small tweaks,  `"alignment-baseline"` and not `"alignmentBaseline"`, and your loops had `y = 0; y <= numRows; y++` instead of `y = 0; y < numRows; y++`, others you will have 26 lines and not 25

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling to understand your issue, but I think you are trying to lay out the numbers in a grid of 101 by 25 inside a container of unknown width. If you set the width of each span to `calc(100%/101)`, you should be able to accomplish it.

```
#game {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px green inset;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  font-family: Cascadia Code;
  width: calc(100%/101);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. I updated the question, added a screenshot of what it should look like.

Comment: I updated the answer to remove the fixed width.

Comment: this works, but there should be no gaps between spans

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a grid?
If it's a game the good thing is after you can address each cell by row and col.

```js
let str = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
    str += '<div>1</div>';
  }
}
document.querySelector('#game').innerHTML = str;
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#gameWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#game {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(25, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(100, 1fr);
  gap: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#game {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px green inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="gameWrapper">
  <div id="game">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when #game is resized to fit the screen between the characters '1' no empty space should appear. i am trying to replicate windows command prompt

Comment: 2 possibilities: 1 - that means number of rows is not 25, number of cols is not 100. Those numbers have to increase or decrease regarding the size of #game. 2- rows are 25, cols 100, font inside each cell has to fill size of 1 cell

Comment: do you need game to be 100% wide?

Comment: if the user's screen is wider then #game, #game should be centered and scaled so it touches top and bottom of the screen. #game should adapt to screen size. the quantity of rows and cols should stay the same regardless of screen resolution.

Comment: regarding your comment, that means that font-size increase to fill the cell. But up to which size? "screen is wider then #game" so #game size has a limit?